# Postman/Newman, how to chain requests based on previous requests responses?

Tags: rest, automated-tests, postman, newman

I see multiple tutorials about Postman/Newman test scripts, however they mostly looks like single requests.

**What is the best way to chain Postman test request based on previous results**, so eg:

- PUT upload request
- Test for e.g. status code. If 200, do POST start-processing the just uploaded file, else stop
- If 200, then do GET to query
- If 200, check JSON against fixed expected JSON output.

Newman seems to run an entire collection independently. I only want to run request 1, which then fires request 2 and request 3 based on output of previous request in that same collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure this in the Tests section in Postman by using

```
if (condition) {
    postman.setNextRequest("NAME OF YOUR REQUEST")
}
```